# expresiones regulares en perl

Tags: regex, perl

compañeros, buen día.

¿Me pueden ayudar, por favor, en cómo construir una expresión regular que me imprima "n/s:" que es un número de serie de un documento?

Lo he intentado de varias formas pero no más no le doy.

```
if ($row =~ (\/[n]/[\/:\^_]\/[s]/g)
{ 
push @impresion, ("$row");


open (EMPLEADOSS,">serie.txt");


foreach my $i (0 .. $#impresion) {

print EMPLEADOSS $impresion[$i];
}
en el if le he intentado 

if ($row =~ (/n/s:/g)

my $numero= (n/s:);
if ($row =~ (/$numero/g)
```

pero no más, no me queda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con

```
if ($row =~ m{n/s:}) {
```

Al poner explícitamente que es una expresión regular con el operador m//, tenemos la opción de usar otros caracteres como delimitadores del patrón. Como el patrón contiene un '/', queda feo o complicado usar las barras diagonales como delimitadores ya que se mezclan con lo que estamos buscando. Por eso, con la presencia de 'm', ponemos como delimitador la pareja de llaves. Ahora ya podemos escribir el patrón tal cual.

De hecho... no es un patrón lo que estamos buscando, sino una subcadena (no hay comodines y demás bichos de los patrones). Por eso, para acelerar el programa un poco se puede reescribir de esta manera:

```
if (-1 != index $row, "n/s:") {
```

Esto lo que hace es buscar "n/s:" dentro de $row. Si lo encuentra, devuelve el índice al carácter donde se encuentra dentro de $row. Si no lo encuentra devuelve -1.

Más información en **perldoc -f index**